# display flex does not break long lines as expected

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, display

Trying to display a list of things in a single line using flex display. I am using angular 7 for development.
Below is the HTML I implemented:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <span>Other:&nbsp;</span>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div *ngFor="let allergy of allergies; let i = index">
      <span *ngIf="i > 0">,</span><span *ngIf="allergy"> {{ allergy }}</span>
      <span *ngIf="!allergy">None</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

d-flex is the bootstrap display class:

```
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

In my component allergies is set to

```
allergies = ['dermatological allergies', 'dust', 'pollen', 'mold'];
```

Display:

[image]

As seen, the list does not break properly and the display is distorted. This happens when the list length exceeds the computed column width. How can I display it as a list that breaks properly as expected? Please let me know if I can improve my question or if I can provide any more information.

Comment: can you provide the d-flex style code ?

Comment: `.d-flex` provides `display: flex;` in bootstrap. Remove that class from the div that wraps the allergies text and the text will not be spaced out in that way. `display: flex;` has a strange effect on text that is the direct child contents.

Comment: @Simran I guess the wrapper div is the culprit. Thank you for promptly pinpointing the problem.

Comment: @realIsComplex no prob! Glad to help!... btw, flexbox can be a real mystery and produce a ton of unexpected results until you wrap your head around it fully. Some good reading to learn more if you like: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <span>Other:&nbsp;</span>
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let allergy of allergies; let i = index">
      <span *ngIf="allergy">{{ allergy }}</span><span *ngIf="i < allergies.length - 1">, </span>
      <span *ngIf="!allergy">None</span>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rokw2) example showing how this looks like.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This does the trick. I guess the child div with flex display was distorting the display. With this, it is pretty neat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With angular, I suggest you to use [Flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) from Angular.

With your to wrap your item, use `row wrap`

With your code, you can also do:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  ...
  ...
    <div *ngFor="let allergy of allergies; let i = index" class="d-flex">
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well. I removed the wrapper div with display flex and added that on the div with ngFor instead as per your suggestion. Thank you!